# VBA - String changes when SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, string, hyperlink, save-as

My code creates a new Excel file, and gathers data into it. Then it should save it into a specified folder (on the hard drive), with a specified name.
The path - with the file name at the end - is built up by the code and stored in a string.
Right before the SaveAs command, I use Debug.Print to check the string, and it's a 100% good.
Still the SaveAs line runs to this error:

"Run-time error '1004':

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file

[here comes the entire path]

There are several possible reasons:

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a"

(The rest is not visible because of the size of the window, but whatever.)

The path in the error message is ok, but instead of the file name there is a 6-character code made of (seemingly) random numbers and letters. And it changes with every run.

How does the filename string get exchanged to that? Can it have anything to do with cloud-based stuff and/or sharepoint and/or syncronization (of which I'm not expert)?
Are there any solutions?
Thanks

Comment: Is your specified folder a OneDrive location?

Comment: The folder is on C:\, but synced to OneDrive. Just realized that my previous comment made no sense, so deleted it. So I had the error exactly on the SaveAs line, before that all's good - including the link, because it works when I have it printed and try from Immediate. Because I only got the error when the link was manually copied, and not when it's picked via dialogbox, I thought that sg in the link changed. Now I see that it has nothing to do with that. The day when I got the error must have been more traffic or sg? Is there another solution than turning the sync of the folder off?